# starting java application using descriptor in chromebook

Tags: java, descriptor, chromebook

There is a Java app that is supported on Windows & Mac and I am trying to run it in chromebook.
To run the app, one would login to website and click an icon that download a file that contains:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<descriptor>
    <type>java</type>
    <name>Market-Q</name>
    ...
    <resource id= ...
    <vm-argument ...
</descriptor>
```

I've already enabled developer mode and installed JVM but not sure what the next steps would be?
Do I need to run java and pass above file as parameter? if so what would be the syntax?
Is there an esier way to do it?
Sorry if there is not much info but I am not sure what technology is being used so I can/t do a search and figure out what to be done. Any hint/tip would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I don't think you're meant to be using that on your local machine. You should have some kind of executable archive, preferably a JAR, that you can download and then run with a Java Virtual Machine.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Makoto, I haven't listed the whole xml file but resouce tags in xml file list required jar files - as well as other required settings. 
I am guessing that I can run java in command line and pass the xml file as argument but not sure if that is right or if so what the syntax would be?